# Addressing to temporary table created through CDatabase::ExecuteSQL

Tags: mfc, odbc, informix

Consider following code and advise, why can I not address the temporary table created in the current session.

```
CDatabase cdb;
CString csConnectionString = "Dsn=prm2;Driver={INFORMIX 3.34 32 BIT};Host=10.XXX.XXX.XXX;Server=SRVNAME;Service=turbo;Protocol=olsoctcp;Database=DBNAME;Uid=user;Pwd=password";
cdb.OpenEx(csConnectionString, CDatabase::noOdbcDialog);
cdb.ExecuteSQL(CString("Set Isolation to Dirty Read"));
...
CString csStatement1 = "SELECT serno FROM TABLE1 into temp ttt_1;"
CString csStatement2 = "DROP TABLE ttt_1";

cdb.ExecuteSQL(csStatement1); // point1
cdb.ExecuteSQL(csStatement2); // point2
...
cdb.Close();
```

At *point1* everything is fine. At *point2* I have:

> The specified table (ttt_1) is not in the database. State:S0002,Native:-206,Origin:[Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]

I tried to specify username as prefix (like `user.ttt_1` or `"user".ttt_1`); I tried to create permanent table within respective statement in *csStatement1* and every time it failed at *point2*. But when I tried to create same temporary table twice within *csStatement1* I got the message that the temporary table already exists in session.

Please advise: what is wrong and how can I address created temporary tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is all to do with [ODBC autocommit mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131281.aspx). By default ODBC uses the option what is defined during the connection, and according to [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/informix) the default settings for Informix is `commitretain=false`.

You have two options: either set it via the connection string (`commitretain=true`) or (better option) via the ODBC. For a set of statements where you'd like to retain the temp table activate the manual commit mode via SqlSetConnectAttr, then execute a few statements and then call SqlEndTran. Please note, that in manual mode you do not need to call `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, as it will start automatically (behaviour similar to Oracle)

Please note that ODBC applications should not use Transact-SQL transaction statements such as BEGIN TRANSACTION, COMMIT TRANSACTION, or ROLLBACK TRANSACTION, but use the ODBC commands.